# Jquery Global Variable Value Changed should be accessed out of the function also

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Common JS file.
In which there is a Function

```
commonDataTables()
```

what i want if i declare a global variable

```
var oTable;
```

and if the value of that variable is changed inside that function. and after calling that function i use the variable, i want to get the updated value of that variable which was updated inside that function..

Please see this little example which i am trying to explain

http://jsfiddle.net/47cs3jnm/2/

Here in The Above Example i created 2 Divs.

The `#OutPut` div is outside the function and the `#InsideDiv` div is inside the `SomeRandomFunction` Function.

so if i change the value of `globalVar` to `1`, it is only changed for the inside function, but the outside function the value of variable is still the same..
Is there some way i can get the updated value from the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I just updated the fiddle, please check:
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47cs3jnm/3/)

Comment: Please answer with a description of what you edited in the code and why you edited it, at least put the relevant snippet in the answer. Don't answer with a link only.

Comment: Love you, You solved the Problem. But Please can you explain why using `var globalVar;` outside the `$('document').ready(function` works as global. but using it inside the document ready dosent work as global..
Im very greatful for your Help but it will be really nice if you also explain me the reason...

Comment: Sure I can explain you, actually function is the only thing in JS which has its own scope. A variable declared inside function can not be directly accessed from outside it. When I moved the variable outside function its became a variable in global scope. But yes global variables should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: oh.. yes document.ready function is a function itself. i didnt thought of that.. xD
Thanks. Next time i will be careful..

Comment: Please put such explanation in the answer (you can [edit] it), not in the comments.